# HDMI Audio Lower than Computer Audio

Tags: windows-7, audio, hdmi

I have two outputs for Audio. One is an audio jack on my monitor that uses HDMI and the other is the built in audio in the computer. I have noticed that audio on the computer is much louder than the audio on the HDMI.  (I can max out the HDMI audio and it be audible but not loud. The Computer audio can be very loud when maxed out.)

Why is that?

Specs:

- ASUS VS229H-P Monitor
- AMD Radeon HD 6670 Graphics Card
- Windows 7 64bit OS
- VIA High Definition Audio on the ASRock N68-VS3 FX Motherboard

Comment: Is the volume turned up on the monitor?

Comment: @DarthAndroid - I feel like an idiot. I looked through the menu but completly overlooked the `Volume` in the menus. Thanks!

Comment: Happens to the best of us! I frequently forget that restarting a windows computer is a valid solution to fixing problems >.> Writing the volume thing up as an answer for you to choose now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the monitor volume is turned up. Many monitors which support audio from an HDMI connection also have their own independent volume control.

Answer (score 2):

Different audio levels and/or audio "normalizing" can very often be reasons for different audio volume levels. I Can't say if that's what's going on here (since there's not really a whole lot to go on). But then, you only asked for probable reasons.